# Problem display the result of beautifulsoup in php

Tags: php, python, beautifulsoup, display

I'm learning how to run a python script and print the result out with php. I wonder why if I write this in my php file:

```
$output = shell_exec('python newfile.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

and this in my python file:

```
print("Hello");
```

everything works fine and when I run the php file the word "*Hello*" is displayed, but if I write the following in my python file, nothing gets displayed:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')

  whatIneed= soup.findAll(True, {"id": ["errors"]})

  list = []
  for x in whatIneed:
      list.append(str(x))

  print(str(list))
```

PS: I need the whole string, with all the html tags, that's why I'm trying to use beautifulsoup.

Comment: And if you run the python script directly from the command line, and not via PHP?

Comment: by the command line everything works fine, but I need these extracted tags to put them in the new php page

Answer (score 0):

In the print statement you have given a variable p. It wasn't used previously, I guess.

```
print(str(list))
```

might help you to print something based on the current piece of code.

Comment: sorry, my fault! there's an edit on my question. The problem wasn't that, when I asked the question I changed a bit my code to make it more readable. Any other idea/suggestion?